# ERROR After Updated Modules at ConTeXt?

Tags: errors, compiling, context, updating, modules

I have problem after update modules at ConTeXt and I can’t use module at my document before I can. My MWE from this link :

http://downloads.ziddu.com/download/23836664/Vektor.rar.html

You can see my screenshoot :

[image: Error]

This below my screenshoot from processing update at Command Prompt

[image: Processing Update]

And Error

```
    Command Line:   C:\context\tex\texmf-mswin\bin\context.exe "vektor.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\skripsi!\Vektor


mtx-context     | run 1: luatex --fmt="C:/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luatex/cont-en" --jobname="vektor" --lua="C:/context/tex/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/formats/luatex/cont-en.lui" --no-parse-first-line --c:currentrun=1 --c:fulljobname="./vektor.tex" --c:input="./vektor.tex" --c:kindofrun=1 --c:maxnofruns=8 "cont-yes.mkiv"
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (rev 5019) 
 \write18 enabled.
open source     > 1 > 1 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-yes.mkiv

ConTeXt  ver: 2014.06.13 01:11 MKIV beta  fmt: 2014.6.13  int: english/english

system          > 'cont-new.mkiv' loaded
open source     > 2 > 2 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-new.mkiv
close source    > 2 > 2 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/cont-new.mkiv
system          > files > jobname 'vektor', input './vektor', result 'vektor'
fonts           > latin modern fonts are not preloaded
languages       > language 'en' is active
open source     > 2 > 3 > D:/skripsi!/Vektor/vektor.tex
resolvers       > modules > 'art-01' is loaded
open source     > 3 > 4 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/s-art-01.mkiv
open source     > 4 > 5 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/type-imp-dejavu.mkiv
close source    > 4 > 5 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/type-imp-dejavu.mkiv
open source     > 4 > 6 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/type-imp-xits.mkiv
open source     > 5 > 7 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/type-imp-texgyre.mkiv
close source    > 5 > 7 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/type-imp-texgyre.mkiv
close source    > 4 > 7 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/type-imp-xits.mkiv
close source    > 3 > 7 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/s-art-01.mkiv
resolvers       > modules > 'abr-02' is loaded
open source     > 3 > 8 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/s-abr-02.tex
resolvers       > modules > 'abr-01' is loaded
open source     > 4 > 9 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/s-abr-01.tex
close source    > 4 > 9 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/s-abr-01.tex
close source    > 3 > 9 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/s-abr-02.tex
open source     > 3 > 10 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/symb-imp-cc.mkiv
close source    > 3 > 10 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/symb-imp-cc.mkiv
fonts           > symbols > library 'cc' loaded
resolvers       > modules > 'oldbibtex' is loaded
open source     > 3 > 11 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/m-oldbibtex.mkiv
open source     > 4 > 12 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/bibl-bib.mkiv
loading         > ConTeXt Bibliography Support / Experimental BibTeX
resolvers       > lua > loading file 'C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/bibl-bib.lua' succeeded
publications    > loading formatting style from 'bxml-apa'
open source     > 5 > 13 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/bxml-apa.mkiv
close source    > 5 > 13 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/bxml-apa.mkiv
close source    > 4 > 13 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/bibl-bib.mkiv
open source     > 4 > 14 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/bibl-tra.mkiv
loading         > ConTeXt Bibliography Support / BibTeX
resolvers       > lua > loading file 'C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/bibl-tra.lua' succeeded
publications    > loading formatting style from 'bibl-apa'
open source     > 5 > 15 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/bib/bibl-apa.tex
close source    > 5 > 15 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/bib/bibl-apa.tex
close source    > 4 > 15 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/bibl-tra.mkiv
close source    > 3 > 15 > C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/m-oldbibtex.mkiv
publications    > wrote a new auxiliary file 'vektor.aux'
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: vektor.aux
The style file: cont-no.bst
I couldn't open database file xampl.bib
---line 3 of file vektor.aux
 : \bibdata{xampl
 :               }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file vektor.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
metapost        > initializing instance 'metafun' using format 'metafun'
metapost        > loading 'metafun' as 'C:/context/tex/texmf-context/metapost/context/base/metafun.mpiv' using method 'default'
metapost        > initializing number mode 'scaled'
backend         > xmp > using file 'C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/lpdf-pdx.xml'
pages           > flushing realpage 1, userpage 1
structures      > begin of sectionblock 'frontpart'
structure       > sectioning > chapter @ level 2 : 0.1 -> Kata Pengantar
structures      > end of sectionblock 'frontpart'
pages           > flushing realpage 2, userpage 1
structure       > sectioning > subject @ level 3 : 0.0.0 -> Daftar Isi
pages           > flushing realpage 3, userpage 2
structure       > sectioning > chapter @ level 2 : 0.1 -> Pendahuluan
structure       > sectioning > section @ level 3 : 0.1.1 -> Instalasi \LATEX \ \index {LATEX} pada Windows \index {Windows} 7

Overfull \hbox (52.10847pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 242--243
 [][][][][] \3>dejavu-10pt-rm-tf-0--0 T[]X Ed-i-tor. Un-duh WinEdt yang berguna dalam pengetikan doku-men da-pat di-un-duh di http://winedt.com
structure       > sectioning > section @ level 3 : 0.1.2 -> Instalasi \CONTEXT \ pada WinEdt 8
pages           > flushing realpage 4, userpage 3

Overfull \hbox (0.95139pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 259--262
 [][][][][] \3>dejavu-10pt-rm-tf-0--0 Tahap UnIn-sta-lasi Jika kamu berkeing-i-nan un-tuk meng-ha-pus add ons Con-TeXt pada WinEdt

Overfull \hbox (104.07617pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 264--265
 \3>dejavu-10pt-rm-tf-0--0 men-cari file con-text.exe dan se-harus-nya file be-rada pada \3>dejavu-10pt-tt-tf-0--0 C:\context\tex\textmf-mswin\bin\context.exe
pages           > flushing realpage 5, userpage 4
structure       > sectioning > section @ level 3 : 0.1.3 -> Memulai dokumen baru
structure       > sectioning > section @ level 3 : 0.1.4 -> Menambah Module dalam \CONTEXT 
pages           > flushing realpage 6, userpage 5
structure       > sectioning > section @ level 3 : 0.1.5 -> Memulai Dokumen Baru dengan Module
pages           > flushing realpage 7, userpage 6
structure       > sectioning > chapter @ level 2 : 0.2 -> Catatan Kaki

Overfull \hbox (5.01855pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 297--298
\3>dejavu-10pt-rm-tf-0--0 bisa menam-bahkan-nya pada catatan kaki(\3>dejavu-10pt-rm-sl-0--0 foot-notes\3>dejavu-10pt-rm-tf-0--0 ) den-gan melakukan su-atu per-in-tah \3>dejavu-10pt-tt-tf-0--0 \footnote
pages           > flushing realpage 8, userpage 7
structure       > sectioning > chapter @ level 2 : 0.3 -> Perataan Rumus Matematika

mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: -1073741819

_____________________________________________________________________

 ConTeXt Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
```

---

I don’t understand **How to fix my problem at Context** ?

Comment: How is this different from the other question?

Comment: Your 'MWE' is far to big (a `.rar` archive of ~350 kB!). Please cut it down to something you can edit into the question itself. In your log, I see `I couldn't open database file xampl.bib`: that's an error and I'd start by trying to fix this.

Comment: Ok, @JosephWright , my problem is third party module can't used at My Document , before I can, you can see my output from that link

Comment: @JosephWright , Third party module can't used at My document after i updated modules.

Comment: No, This question is same from my quetion before

Comment: Please try the following. (1) Put your files into a folder that doesn't contain an exclamation mark. Just in case. (2) Please try to make a minimal example that crashes. I suggest you to concentrate on bibliography. Hans is currently in the middle of heavy modifications of the bib module and I wouldn't be surprized if some change broke the old functionality. (The new bib module with a different user interface doesn't even run bibtex any longer.)

Comment: @MojcaMiklavec , not only on bibliography , i try make a simpleslides with Simpleslides Module, i get a error, Why?

Comment: @HirWanto: there has been a change in the internal macro due to which simpleslide does not load. This should be fixed soon.

Comment: @Aditya Oh, sorry i don't know that any change in the internal macro, so i can't use third party module at my document in ConTeXt, any module is not changed ?