# Problem Update Module at ConTeXt?

Tags: errors, compiling, context, output, modules

From my question before : [ERROR After Updated Modules at ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184730/error-after-updated-modules-at-context)
Since I updated third party modules at ConTeXT, i get problem can't use modules at My ConTeXt document and I always get a message like this :

[image: Error running From WinEdit 8]

Before I can use modules, I know this question equal my question before

**How to fix my problem at ConTeXt ?**